# save from list does not work some times in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a repeat rows in table.In which i have I have checkbox columns and also text columns.I have to save the whole repeat columns with the modified checkbox.List can maintain the changes.but some times the save function does not hit.can anyone help me what i have made wrongly

```
  <tr ng-repeat="Screenrights in lstScreenAccessDetails">
                    <td class="txt-center" ng-bind="lstScreenAccessDetails[$index].ModuleName">
                    </td>
                    <td class="txt-center" ng-bind="lstScreenAccessDetails[$index].ScreenName">
                    </td>
                    <td class="txt-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="lstScreenAccessDetails[$index].Create" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="txt-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="lstScreenAccessDetails[$index].Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="txt-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="lstScreenAccessDetails[$index].Delete" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="txt-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="lstScreenAccessDetails[$index].View" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

// Save

```
        $scope.Save = function () {
            debugger;
            var httpreq = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'ScreenAccessRights.aspx/Save',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'dataType': 'json'
                },

                data: { ROLEID: $scope.SelectedRole.RoleCode, SCREENLIST: $scope.lstScreenAccessDetails }

            }
            $http(httpreq).success(function (response) {

                alert("Saved Successfully.");

            })

        };


//Service
```

//SAVE
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
        public static List Save(string ROLEID, List SCREENLIST)
        {
            List lstScreenAccessDetails = new List();
            try
            {

```
            ResponseScreenAccessRights response = new ResponseScreenAccessRights();

            RequestScreenAccessRights request = new RequestScreenAccessRights();
            request.requestScreenAccessRightsEntity = new ScreenAccessRightsEntity();
            request.requestScreenAccessRightsEntity.RoleId = ROLEID;
            request.requestScreenAccessRightsEntity.lstScreenAccessDetails = SCREENLIST;
            request.requestScreenAccessRightsEntity.CreatedBy = "Admin";
            response = new ScreenAccessRightsBC().InsertScreenAccessRightsBC(request);

            if (response.result)
            {
                DataTable ds = response.dtScreenAccessRightsDetails;

                lstScreenAccessDetails = (from DataRow row in response.dtScreenAccessRightsDetails.Rows

                                          select new ScreenAccessDetails
                                          {
                                              ModuleId = row["MODULEID"].ToString(),
                                              ModuleName = row["MODULENAME"].ToString(),
                                              ScreenId = row["SCREENID"].ToString(),
                                              ScreenName = row["SCREENNAME"].ToString(),
                                              Create = Convert.ToBoolean(row["SCREENCREATE"]),
                                              Edit = Convert.ToBoolean(row["SCREENEDIT"]),
                                              Delete = Convert.ToBoolean(row["SCREENDELETE"].ToString()),
                                              View = Convert.ToBoolean(row["SCREENVIEW"].ToString())
                                          }).ToList();



            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return lstScreenAccessDetails;
    }
```

Comment: Provide your fiddle to show what you've tried

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. When you ask a question, try to provide more details. Especially your code.Otherwise, I don't think anyone can answer your question precisely.

Comment: I hav provided code for your reference....

Comment: 1) In debug mode make sure the method is being hit each time. 2) Make sure both of your objects are defined, and consistent. Also, sharing your `WebMethod` could be of value here.

Comment: I have added my webmethod also.Can anyone give answer for this problem